# Prove a continuous function agrees with countable intersection of compact sets

Tags: general-topology

> Let $X$ be a $T_2$ space, $Y$ a $T_1$ space, $f:X\to Y$ a continuous function and $\left\{K_n\right\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ a decreasing (in the sense of $\supseteq$) family of compact sets in $X$.
>
> Prove that $f\left(\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N} K_n\right)=\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N} f\left(K_n\right)$.

The $\subseteq$ part of the proof is easy, since it holds for any sets $K_n$ and function $f$. I think I managed to prove the $\supseteq$ part too, but I am not certain that it is a valid proof, so I thought I'd check.

$\\$

$\Delta:$ Let $y$ be an arbitrary element of $Y$. Since $Y$ is $T_1$, $\{y\}$ is closed in $Y$, i.e., $y\in {\mathcal F}_Y$ and thus, $f^{-1}\left(\{y\}\right)\in {\mathcal F}_X$, since $f$ is continuous.

Now suppose the equality doesn't hold, i.e., $(\exists y\in \bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N} f(K_n))\ f^{-1}(\{y\})\ \cap\ \left(\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N} K_n\right) = \emptyset$. Since $X$ is $T_2$, $(\forall n\in \mathbb N)\ K_n\in \mathcal F_X$. Thus, because $K_n$ is a decreasing family, $\mathcal C=\{K_n \cap f^{-1}(\{y\})\ |\ n\in\mathbb N\}$ is a family of closed sets in $K_1 \cap f^{-1}(\{y\})$ with FIP, but $\bigcap\mathcal C=\emptyset$. That means that $K_1 \cap f^{-1}(\{y\})$ is not compact, which is a contradiciton, since it is a closed subspace of the compact space $K_1$. Therefore, it must be that $(\forall y\in \bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N} f(K_n))\ f^{-1}(\{y\})\ \cap\ \left(\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N} K_n\right) \neq \emptyset$, i.e., that $f\left(\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N} K_n\right) \supseteq \bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N} f\left(K_n\right)$. $\square$

$\\$

Is this proof correct, or have I missed some details? I can provide any clarifications necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $\supseteq$ and $\subseteq$ interchanged in the paragraph immediately under the highlighted text: it’s the $\subseteq$ part that’s easy, and the $\supseteq$ part that you go on to prove.

The proof is correct, though it could be expressed a bit more clearly, and you don’t need an argument by contradiction:

> Let $K=\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}K_n$, and suppose that $y\in\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}f[K_n]$. Let $F=f^{-1}[\{y\}]$; $Y$ is $T_1$, so $\{y\}$ is closed in $Y$, and $f$ is continuous, so $F$ is closed in $X$. Let $n\in\Bbb N$; then $y\in f[K_n]$, so $F\cap K_n\ne\varnothing$. Clearly $\langle F\cap K_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is a non-increasing nest of closed subsets of the compact set $K_0$, so $$F\cap K=F\cap\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}K_n=\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}(F\cap K_n)\ne\varnothing\;,$$ and hence $y\in f[K]$. Thus, $$\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}f[K_n]\subseteq f\left[\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}K_n\right]\;,$$ and the result follows.

Comment: Ah, yes, you're right, it's unnecessary to use contradition. Thanks for confirming that it's correct! And yes, I had the directions correct in my notes, but copied them here incorrectly.

Comment: @ryagami: You’re welcome! (Yes, I figured that it was probably just a typo.)